# ListView onItemClickListener is returning wrong position after animation

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with a custom BaseAdaptor, which doesn't do anything fancy, just selects the correct string to display in each row.

My issue is that my onItemClickListener which is attached to the ListView seems to be selecting/returning the wrong index. More specifically it's selecting the index below the row that is actually trying to be pressed.

So when i try and tap the first row, I can see that the second row is highlighted, and the onItemClickListener returns position 1 as opposed to 0. Similarly, when I try and press the 2nd row, the 3rd row is highlighted etc.. Interestingly, when I try and tap the area just above the ListView, the 1st row is highlighted, even though the ListView clearly doesn't extend above which I can see by setting a different background colour.

The one strange thing that I am doing however is animating this listView up and down behind another view in a FrameLayout. This seems to be related to the issue as if i render the ListView straight away on screen, all the taps seem to register correctly. Once I animate it, the taps don't register correctly anymore.

Here is my animation code:

```
Boolean shouldOpen = !isDropdownShowing;

RelativeLayout selectionView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.selectedView); //The view that the list is being animated behind
int listHeight = dropdownListView.getHeight();
int heightOfSelectionView = selectionView.getHeight();

TranslateAnimation translateAnimation;
if (shouldOpen) {
    translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation (0.0f, 0.0f, heightOfSelectionView - listHeight, heightOfSelectionView);
    dropdownListView.setY(heightOfSelectionView);
} else {
   translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation (0.0f, 0.0f, heightOfSelectionView, heightOfSelectionView - listHeight);
   dropdownListView.setY(heightOfSelectionView - listHeight);
}

translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
translateAnimation.setDuration(300L);
translateAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
dropdownListView.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
```

Just in case here is how I'm initialising this ListView:

```
dropdownListView = new ListView(getContext());
dropdownListView.setAdapter(new EventsSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), options));
dropdownListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("dropdown", "itemClicked at index " + position);
        selectOption(position);
        handleEventSelectionRowClicked();
    }
});
```

And here is the BaseAdapter:

```
private class EventsSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<String> options;
    int selectedIndex;

    public EventsSpinnerAdapter(Context context, List data)
    {
        inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        options = data;
        selectedIndex = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return options.size()-1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return options.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        if (position >= selectedIndex) {
            return position+1;
        } else {
            return position;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        }

        ((TextView)convertView).setText(options.get((int) getItemId(position)));
        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        }

        ((TextView)convertView).setText(options.get((int) getItemId(position)));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

## EDIT

It turns out it was an issue with the animation. I still don't quite understand why my original code did not work but I found that adding a listener which sets the frame again and clears animation works.

```
translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if (shouldOpen) {
            isDropdownShowing = true;
            dropdownListView.setY(heightOfSelectionView);
        } else {
            isDropdownShowing = false;
            dropdownListView.setY(heightOfSelectionView - listHeight);
        }
        dropdownListView.clearAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Comment: y this return options.size()-1;

Comment: Because I don't want the currently selected option to appear in the list.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
dropdownListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Log.d("dropdown", "itemClicked at index " + position);
    selectOption(position);
    handleEventSelectionRowClicked();
}
});
```

its working for me 
i am not using  `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()`

this is my code

```
lvs.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView names = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.from);
            TextView emails = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.date);

        }
    });
```

Comment: @raj : if u r not using `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` then what r u using check ur import of `OnItemClickListener`

Comment: @raj: Sorry I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to say here. It looks like the same thing...